# Warning: mysql_result() [function.mysql-result]: Unable to jump to row 0 on MySQL result index 5 in profile.php on line 11

Tags: php, mysql

When I try to access `profile.php?u=destiny`

```
//$result = mysql_query('SELECT name FROM 
$imageresult = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM imagetable WHERE id = '$id'") or die(mysql_error());
$u = mysql_result($imageresult, 0 ,"name") or die(mysql_error());
//error_reporting(E_ALL);
if (isset($id) && (!isset($u))) {
}
```

> Warning: mysql_result() [function.mysql-result]: Unable to jump to row
>   0 on MySQL result index 5 in profile.php on line 11

Comment: Your query probably did not return any rows - perhaps `$id` doesn't contain what you expect it to.  Check that `mysql_num_rows($imageresult) > 0`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you can avoid it, please don't use the `mysql_*` functions, they are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ) . Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you cannot decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you want to learn, [here is a good PDO-related tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This warning means that there is no row in the `$imageresult` var. Check it out, this should work:

```
$imageresult = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM imagetable WHERE id = '$id'") or die(mysql_error());
if (mysql_num_rows($imageresult) > 0) {
  $u = mysql_result($imageresult, 0 ,"name") or die(mysql_error());
  if (isset($id) && (!isset($u))) {
  }
}
```

Comment: @Caiapfas Great! If this was the answer that solved your problem go ahead and accept it :)