# PHP mysql_result error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, session

My SESSION username is Hassan

This is my PHP code:

```
$user = $_SESSION['username'];
echo $user;
$sql = mysql_query('SELECT `full_name` FROM `users` WHERE username="$user"');
$full_name = mysql_result($sql,0);
echo $full_name;
```

To make sure there is a `$_SESSION['username']` I echo the `$user` and the result I get is perfect, this is what I get when I goto home.php:

> Hassan
>
> Warning: mysql_result(): Unable to jump to row 0 on MySQL result index 5 in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHP\Projects\UserSys\home.php on line 15

I have now ticked the correct answer, question solved close post.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: There is same issue here please check it out.

 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12649594/warning-mysql-result-function-mysql-result-unable-to-jump-to-row-0-on-mysq

Comment: @MazIqbal Yes, but the issue is not caused by the same problem: the issue is something totally different, as you can read in jszobody's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to stick your `$user` variable in a single-quote string. It won't be evaluated.

Simply change your query to use double quotes:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT `full_name` FROM `users` WHERE username='$user'");
```

Though while this should fix your immediate issue, please realize you are using deprecated `mysql_*` functions, and potentially opening yourself to SQL injection. You should be escaping your query params at least, ideally using prepared statements.