# PHP MySQL unable to jump to row 0

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, registration

I recently started studying webdevelopment and for the first project we have to make a very simple login and registration function. now I got somewhere but suddenly I started getting this error.

> Unable to jump to row 0 on MySQL result index 4.

This is the code where I get the error.

```
$conn = mysql_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database) or die("!Server");

if(!$conn){
    die("Connection error: " . mysql_error());
}else{
    echo "connection made";
}

$select_db= mysql_select_db($database, $conn);

if(!$select_db){
    die("Database selection failed:: " . mysql_error());
}else{
    echo "database selected";
}

$login_user = $_GET['username'];
$select_password = "SELECT `password` FROM `members` WHERE `username` = '$login_user'";
$result = mysql_query($select_password);

if(!$result){
    die("Could not fetch the data " . mysql_error());
}

$password = mysql_result($result, 0);

echo $password;
```

I know there are other posts asking the same question but none of them where really helpful.

hope someone is able to help me.

Thanks for reading :)

Comment: Run this query directly in the database & check the result!!

Comment: make sure `$login_user` is set before your enter it in your query. may be use !empty() check before the query

Comment: Note: The `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, they will be removed from PHP in future versions and your code will stop working then. You should not write new code using them, use [`mysqli_*` or PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) instead.

Comment: can u please post dd result of $result and $password ?

Comment: If you are just starting to learn php & mysql, I **highly recommend** that you **not learn mysql**. Do yourself a favor and learn using the most modern language of [pdo_mysql](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php)

Comment: The script is also prone to sql injections (see http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php ) and lacks error handling. Each and every of the mysql_* functions may return something indiciating an error (usually `false`). You have to check the return values - always. If an error is indicated, your script must handle it, instead of blindly moving on. If you don't like that, switch to PDO and PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION which allows you "install" the error handling (only) at the level where you need it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Warning: mysql\_result() \[function.mysql-result\]: Unable to jump to row 0 on MySQL result index 5 in profile.php on line 11](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12649594/warning-mysql-result-function-mysql-result-unable-to-jump-to-row-0-on-mysq)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible that this row:

```
password = mysql_result($result, 0);
```

Cannot get rows when it does not match anything which is why you get the error.

Try instead:

```
if( $password = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ) {
    echo $password['password'];
} else {
    echo 'no match';
}
```

See if that helps.

However, you really should move from mysql_* to PDO or mysqli.

Comment: This will still bring up the error message if no results are found.

Comment: You are correct and I changed the mysql_result to mysql_fetch_assoc to avoid the error. Thanks for the note. Just copy pasted wrong part.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest to work with [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), instead of mysql_... functions.
Not only because it's newer and object oriented but also because mysql... is deprecated.
So my answer is with PDO

From your code example I assume you have variables of servername, database, username & password. So to connect with PDO will look like this:

```
$con = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$database", $username, $password);
```

Then you can take your $_GET parameter using [filter_input](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php), which is also more suggested. Simple assignment look like this:

```
$login_user = filter_input(INPUT_GET,'username');
```

and then to run & fetch query like this:

```
$result_query = $con->query("SELECT `password` FROM `members` WHERE `username` = '$login_user'");
$result = $result_query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Now *$result* is an associative array, so to get password just use:

```
echo $result['password'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks alot for the help :) out of these answers I got everything I needed and now I am also going to switch to PDO for the final release though I am gonna stay with MySQL for now since I have to turn it in by monday.

Thanks alot :)

Comment: This is not an answer to your question. If one of the answers reflects your solution, mark it as solved. You can thank in a comment.

Answer (score -1):

Change this:

```
$select_password = "SELECT `password` FROM `members` WHERE `username` = '$login_user'";
```

Into this:

```
$select_password = "SELECT password FROM members WHERE username = '$login_user'";
```

Comment: Why this should change something?

Comment: Because you are now looking into tables. You should look into data in the tables.

Comment: You only removed the ` from the query. this should change nothing.

Comment: maybe if you could change username = '$login_user' "; to username = ' " . $login_user ;    Its all about precise coding.

Comment: This will change nothing again (you forgot to close with ``'`` should be then ``username = ' " . $login_user . "'";`` [still change nothing])